# Avoiding eval(), I need a way to pass multiple arguments to a variable function

Tags: javascript, function, eval

Trying to pass multiple parameters to a variable function call..

```
function myFunction(myvar,time){
    alert(myvar);   
}

t_function = "myFunction";
t_params = "haha,hehe";
window[t_function](t_params);
```

I basically need to mimic this call

```
myFunction("haha","hehe");
```

I can't set a specific amount of params in the variable function call, like

```
// I will not know how many params a function will need.
window[t_function](t_params1,t_params2,etc);
```

Any ideas? I'm tempted to use eval.

------ ended up doing this -----

function myFunction(myvar1,myvar2){
        alert(myvar1 + " and " + myvar2);

```
}

t_function = "myFunction";
t_params = [];
t_params[0] = "haha";
t_params[1] = "hehe";

window[t_function].apply(this,t_params);
```

thanks all, specially to Joseph the Dreamer

Comment: You can actually declare the array as `var t_params = ['hello','world'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which takes in a value for `this` in your function, and an array of arguments:

```
window[t_function].apply(this,[arg1,arg2,...,argN]);
```

And the function will receive it as:

```
function myFunction(arg1,arg2,...,argN){...}
```

Every value passed into the invoked function can be accessed via the array-like `arguments`. This is useful especially when the arguments are dynamic. Thus, you can do something like:

```
function myFunction(){
  var arg1 = arguments[0]; //hello
  var arg2 = arguments[1]; //world
}

//different ways of invoking a function
myFunction('hello','world');
myFunction.call(this,'hello','world');
myFunction.call(this,['hello','world']);
```

Comment: will that pass an array into my function? or arguments as if they were called directly myFunction(arg1,arg2) . because if that passes an array into the function then i have to mod my function to process array as parameters/arguments

Comment: @BrownChiLD updated the answer, and read the documentation for `apply`

Answer (score 1):

If you can reliably use `,` as a separator, try this:

```
window[t_function].apply(null,t_params.split(","));
```

Comment: I think `t_params` is a string of variable names not values.

Comment: "i basically need to mimic this call myFunction("haha","hehe");" Strings, not variables ;)